# Liouville's equation and Cauchy problem $\dot{x} = f(x(t),t)$ in optimal control

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, optimal-control, sturm-liouville

In a guest lecture about optimal control problem, the speaker introduce the following:

The Liouville's equation encodes a superposition al all classical solutions soving Cauchy problem:

1. Liouville's equation:  $$\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t}+ \mbox{div }(f\mu)=\mu_0-\mu_T$$
2. Cauchy Problem:   $$\dot{x}(t) = f(t,x(t))$$

$\mu$ might be of different meanings in different topics; in this lecture, $\mu$ is a occupation measure, $\mu_0$ is the measure evaluated at the initial time. $f(t,x)$ is a nonlinear system. Note: the nonlinear system can actually include the control, i.e., $\dot{x} = f(x,u,t)$ to capture the optimal control problem:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& {\underset{u}{\text{min}}}
& &\int_0^{t_f} l(t,x,u)\\
& \text{s.t.} & & \dot{x}=f(t,x(t),u(t)) \quad \text{a.e. on }[0,t_f]\\
             \end{aligned} 
\end{equation*}

---

I am very confused about "**Liouville's equation encodes a superposition al all classical solutions of $\dot{x}= f(x,t)$**". Could anyone please provide the fundamental background or introduction note about this?

I even have no idea how to relate both stuffs; they look quite different for me.

Comment: This is an idea which looks fascinating and I would love to know more.  Can you define your terms in greater detail or provide references--preferably online references?

Comment: @RobertLewis This is from Prof. Henrion in LAAS-CNRS: http://www.eeci-institute.eu/GSC2011/Photos-EECI/EECI-GSC-2011-M4/lmiII5.pdf

Comment: OK, got it.  Thanks.  Will try to check it out soon!